# Loading data into Titan

Tags: titan, rexster

I am currently running Titan Server (0.4) [via bin/titan.sh -c cassandra-es start] and load the sample data using rexster-console:

```
rexster[groovy]> g = rexster.getGraph("graph")
rexster[groovy]> GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g)
```

How can I do the same thing above using a RexsterClient in java? Essentially, Is it possible to get access to graph without me having to embed all this in client.execute()?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've created the graph you can access it with `RexsterClient`.  You shouldn't need to recreate the graph again with it as the data is already in Cassandra.  Just specify the graph name when constructing your `RexsterClient` instance (in the case of Titan Server the graph name is just "graph"):

```
RexsterClient client = RexsterClientFactory.open("localhost", "graph");
List<Map<String, Object>> results = client.execute("g.v(4).map");
```

That will initialize "g" and allow you to just issue some Gremlin against the Graph of the Gods sample data set. You can read more about the options for `RexsterClient` [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/RexPro-Java).

Comment: Stephen, The reason I needed a graph was so I could frame my vertices using FramedGraph. Is it not recommended on the client side?

Comment: I don't use Frames all that much, so I don't have a lot of personal experience with it, but I believe I've been told in the past that the cost to frame a graph isn't much. so you could get the Graph instance in the same manner I explained and pass it to `FramedGraph` in your `execute` operation.  Or you could issue `RexsterClient` messages in-session (which is a little more work) and the bindings would be maintained between requests, in which case you could maintain a reference to the `FramedGraph`.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with the in-session approach. What would be a good place to look for it? Having a frame would let me fetch other relations without having to query for each one of them individually on my own.I am not sure embedding the frames in client would achieve this but I will try and update this post.

Comment: You would construct your own RexProMessage instances manually (https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/blob/master/rexster-protocol/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/rexster/client/RexsterClient.java#L110)  You can read more about the format here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/RexPro-Messages

Comment: sharmami, have you managed to get a FramedGraph on the client side? Would you mind to publish your solution?

Comment: msander, I ditched framedgraph in favor of rexster giving me JSON via gremlin.